# CakePHP 3.x how to point the templates to a file inside a Plugin?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, themes, cakephp-3.0

According to http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses,

the way to point to a list of template containers, is to create a file inside `config` folder.

> ```
> // In a View class
> $this->loadHelper('Form', [
>     'templates' => 'app_form',
> ]);
> ```
>
> This would load the tags in config/app_form.php. This file should
>   contain an array of templates indexed by name:

How do I do the same by pointing at a file **inside** a Plugin instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I do the same by pointing at a file inside a Plugin instead?

Guess as everywhere else in the framework? Dot notation: `PluginName.app_form`

If that is not working it should be added to the framework to be consistent.